# How to fix "no host available" while using Create Keyspaces

Tags: cassandra

I just installed Cassandra. When I tried to create keyspace I am getting error message : NoHostAvailable. Response from the running create keyspace command. Any idea what am i doing wrong?

```
cqlsh> CREATE KEYSPACE cycling
   ...   WITH REPLICATION = {
   ...    'class' : 'SimpleStrategy',
   ...    'replication_factor' : 1
   ...   };
NoHostAvailable:
cqlsh> show host;
Connected to Test Cluster at 127.0.0.1:9042.
cqlsh>
```

Comment: do you see anything in the `system.log` on cassandra host?

Comment: Thanks for the response, I checked the logs and found the error and was able to fix it. Port was being used by another application. I changed the port.